# The apple-app-site-association file format error

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

```
    *I have error message from API Validation Tool from Apple*   

      **The apple-app-site-association file was found but it doesn’t follow the required format. Learn how to format the apple-app-site-association file.**  

    *My apple-app-site-association file:  

        {
            "applinks": {
                "apps": [],
                "details": [
                    {
                        "appID": "TeamId.com.Company.AppName",
                        "paths": [
                            "/path1-*",
                            "/path2",
                            "/path3-*",
                            "/path4"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
    }
```

I saw this videos from WWDC 2015 "Seamless linking to your Apps" and "Introducing Search API" and read this App Search Programming Guide.

My website have an SSL certificate (from Authority certified) and my apple-app-site-association is inside https://www.mywebsite.com/apple-app-site-association

I don't know what is wrong with the file. I think syntax error can be but I cant see it.*

Answer (score 4):

seems like you should replace TeamId.com.Company.AppName with your REAL TeamId and REAL bundle id.

Look at this one for exmaple
https://routes.tips/apple-app-site-association

It`s nor signed, but working and passing validation

Comment: No My team id and bundle id are correct ,I have checked it no problem is seen about them

Answer (score 1):

Dears

There is one more issue about TeamID, especially more than one apps in one accout.

Please [use the App IDs prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731371/applinks-in-ios-9-not-working) into your appID of app-app-site-assiciation.